# Can we add one more localization language to an iOS app which is in the app store without adding a new version

Tags: ios, iphone, nslocalizedstring

Using iTunesConnect is there any way to add one more language for localization without uploading a new ipa to the store

Comment: No, there is not.  Localization text is included in the app bundle, and that can't be changed without a new submission.

Comment: Note: if you want to do something for the future, you can do localization manually (google for examples, including from Apple), and have some mechanism for the app to update itself regularly.

Answer (score 2):

No you cant do this. You have to add one more localization file and upload it again.